# Black background still shows after I overlay it to another picture: Python OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am able to overlay the picture with the black background, but I am not able to overlay it when I remove the black background. I know I am removing it because when I save the file, the background is removed, but if I try to add the new image, it's still going to have the black background. If I directly add the transformed image, I get the following error:

**could not broadcast input array from shape (45,56,4) into shape (45,56,3). I'm not sure what the third dimension is.**

`final_image` is just a regular .JPG file that has some polylines drawn on top of it

EDIT: I wish I could give a traceback error, but this is the only ValueError exception I get when running in Visual Studio Code. I've pasted my entire function for this problem now. My main issue is that I can't get the transparency to show up on the final output, it still outputs as black.

```
#Check if file exists
fileExists = exists(filename)
if not fileExists:
    print("File does not exist")
    return -1

#Read image
image = cv.imread(filename)
hsv = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_blue = np.array([30,60,180])
upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
lower_red = np.array([160,70,140])
upper_red = np.array([170,130,255])
lower_green = np.array([29,60,170])
upper_green = np.array([40,100,260])
lower_orange = np.array([10,85,200])
upper_orange = np.array([20,120,255])

red_mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
blue_mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
green_mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
orange_mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_orange, upper_orange)

combined_image = cv.addWeighted(red_mask, 0.5, blue_mask, 0.5, 0)
brighter_image = cv.convertScaleAbs(combined_image, alpha=2.0, beta=100)
combined_image = cv.addWeighted(combined_image, 0.5, green_mask, 0.5, 0)
brighter_image = cv.convertScaleAbs(combined_image, alpha=2.0, beta=100)
combined_image = cv.addWeighted(combined_image, 0.5, orange_mask, 0.5, 0)

brighter_image = cv.convertScaleAbs(combined_image, alpha=2.0, beta=100)

#Blur using n * n kernel
blurred_image = cv.blur(brighter_image, (26,26))

# Apply Hough tranform on the blurred image
detected_circles = cv.HoughCircles(blurred_image, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 200, param1=25, param2=20, minRadius=50, maxRadius=90)

#Draw circles that are detected
if detected_circles is not None:
    #Convert circle parameters a, b, and r to integers
    detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(detected_circles))

    coord = []
    for pt in detected_circles[0, :]:
        tempCoord = []
        a, b, r = pt[0], pt[1], pt[2]
        tempCoord.append(a)
        tempCoord.append(b)
        coord.append(tempCoord)

        #Draw the circumfrence of the circle
        cv.circle(image, (a,b), r, (0,255,0), 2)

        #Draw a small circle of (of radius 1) to show the center
        cv.circle(image, (a,b), 1, (0,0,255), 3)

coords = np.array([coord],np.int32)
final_image = cv.polylines(image, [coords], isClosed=True, color=(0,0,0), thickness=2)
#final_image = cv.cvtColor(final_image, cv.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

logo = cv.imread('opencvlogo.PNG')
resized_logo = cv.resize(logo, (56,45), interpolation = cv.INTER_AREA)
gray_resized_logo = cv.cvtColor(resized_logo, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, alpha = cv.threshold(gray_resized_logo, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
b, g, r = cv.split(resized_logo)
rgba = [b, g, r, alpha]
dst = cv.merge(rgba, 4)
new_logo = cv.imread('logo_clr.png')
new_logo = cv.cvtColor(new_logo, COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
cv.imshow("transparent logo", new_logo)
x_offset=y_offset=0
final_image[y_offset:y_offset+new_logo.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset+new_logo.shape[1]] = new_logo 
cv.imshow("Detected Circles", final_image)

k = cv.waitKey(0)
if k == ord('s'):
    filename = input("Enter the filename to save: ")
    cv.imwrite(filename, final_image)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: One of your images might be missing a channel. Print both shapes _before_  the slicing to figure out their dimensions.

Comment: `4` means `R,G,B,transparency`. Maybe first you should check `.shape` for image. Maybe it is file with transparency (alpha channel) but code may expect only `RGB`. You didn't show FULL error message so we don't know which line makes problem - and we can't read in your mind to get it. You have to describe all details in question.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.